# Exception during discrete event execution

Tags: anylogic

I am measuring time of  two paths separately by adding timeMeasure blocks as i shown in the image below. I want to calculate average time spent in the system of this two paths by adding time measure. but a error will occur as follows;
[image: Error]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are mixing the agents that passed through `timeMeasureStart` and `timeMeasureStart1`. Either you can duplicate your flow starting from `delay` block below and bring the `timeMeasureEnd1` there, or split the time measurement process into two parts. One until the `delay` block, the other after that.

Comment: That delay block is to represent a waiting area. two different customers will go to one waiting area and that's why I connected that two paths to delay block.

Comment: use the custom approach that I have in the previous answer. set `agent.enterTime` and `agent.leaveTime` and you control what happens with them

Comment: is this method correct? https://postimg.cc/vDczF3js

Comment: should work in my opinion